# How to get a second cin to work when the first has a while loop to take in an unknown size input

Tags: c++, cin

I have been trying to figure out how to get a simple program to work, however I am getting hung up on taking user input from the console. I am able to take in a list of integers (eg. 3 5 3 2 1 8 9) into a vector, however I need to also take in one more user input for the number I need to check if it is inside the vector.

When I run the code, *it always skips over the second cin* and does not allow any more console input, finishing the program. My best understanding is that since cin does not take white space into account, using a second line will not work. However, I do not understand after breaking the while loop it will skip over my next cin statement.
Another way I can think of getting it to work is possibly using getline for the first line of input, however I am not sure of how to get that to work especially when converting back to an integer.

Sample Input for line 1 on console: **2 7 6 7 8 5 67 54 3**  (these will go into a vector)

Sample Input for line 2 on console: **54** *(this will just go into another variable num)*

```
int i;
vector<int> v;
int num;

cout << "When finished entering numbers type any letter and hit enter" << endl << "Enter list of numbers: ";
while (cin >> i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}

cout << endl << "Enter number to be found: ";
cin >> num;
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is reading integers from the input stream `std::cin`, so if you enter a letter `std::cin` goes into an error state and will remain there until you explicitly clear the error state.

To clear the error state, call [`cin.clear()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/). But invalid input remains in the stream. To ignore all the remaining characters in the stream, call [`cin.ignore()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) like this:

```cpp
std::cin::ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

So please add following two lines after the while loop, then your program should work as expected.

```cpp
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Output:

```
When finished entering numbers type any letter and hit enter
Enter list of numbers: 1
2 
3
4
abcde

Enter number to be found: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on it, this explanation clears it up on why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Call `cin.clear()` after the loop. This should clear all error flags.

In your case you might want to skip the next newline aswell with `cin.ignore(10000, '\n')`.

Comment: I tried this just now, it still skips over my second cin input that I want and finishes the program.

Comment: Can you try add `cin.ignore`?

Comment: I added it how Aamir suggested, and it allows me to enter a second number to the console. I will also try your suggestion out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting multiple kinds of input from the user--`int` and not `int`--you can also read into a `std::string` in the loop condition and then explicitly test if the read text can be converted to an `int`.

```cpp
std::string input;
std::vector<int> v;
while(std::cin >> input)
{
    try
    {
        v.push_back(std::stoi(input));
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument&) // input is not an int
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This way, `std::cin` is always in a good state. When you get to the second `std::cin >> num`, there's no error in `std::cin` and there's no extra data in the stream.

Comment: I see, I did not look at it like this. I will try this out as well, as it seems bypassing an error is more of a workaround.

Comment: @bakedpotato12385 Thanks for the edit. I've been writing too much Python lately.